# Advance Search problem

Tags: search, word, pdf

I am using advance serach result webpart for searching contents. I want to display  only word document and pdf doucument in result webpart.How it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: 
http://www.knowledgelake.com/blog/using-sharepoint-search-scopes-knowledgelake-search

This will limit your search to PDF's only, so implement another scope for the word documents.